# Cannot serialize enum with Jackson and Jaxb annotation using @XmlEnumValue

Tags: java, json, enums, jaxb, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.2.2 with JAXB annotated classes. I would like to get enums serialized as int numbers. Because of the XML (as I want the same behaviour for XML as well) there is necessity to use @XmlEnumValue etc. All fine.
For serialization to JSON this annotation according the documentation of Jackson is supported but so far no luck to make it work for JSON (XML is fine).

```
@XmlType(name = "Period")
public enum Period {

@XmlEnumValue("11")
DAILY("Daily"),
@XmlEnumValue("1")
WEEKLY("Weekly"),
@XmlEnumValue("2")
SEVENTH_DAY("3");
private final String value;
...
```

Produced JSON still looks following:

```
        "OvertimeRates": {
        "DAILY": [
          {
            "AfterHours": -19497,
            "Rate": 3.7003279564106983
          }
        ]
      },
```

While I would expect that instead DAILY I would see 11.

My Code:

```
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        mapper.registerModule(jaxbAnnotationModule);

        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
//        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_INDEX, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        final PosData posData = dataGenerator.getPosData();
        try {
            mapper.writeValue(new File(PATH_TO_FILE), posData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

I tried to experiment with  mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_INDEX, false); but that didn't help either.

Any idea what I've missed?

Ta

Comment: It works pretty good when your enum is a property in a class, for example.  In your scenario Period is a key in a map or something like that. Could you change your POJO class or JSON? If no, probably, you have to write your own key serializer on map serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show your POJO class which contains `OvertimeRates` property so I can only guess that this is the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Could you change it to [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)? It should work properly if you change your property to:

```
private EnumMap<Period, POJO1> overtimeRates = new EnumMap<Period, POJO1>(Period.class);
```